# Add alt text to image posts using XML-RPC/functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, image, xml-rpc

I am using the following part of code to upload images using `xmlrpc` in my wordpress site:

```
$content = array(
            'name' => $title.".".$ext,
            'type' => $type,
            'bits' => new IXR_Base64(file_get_contents($imgur)),
            true
        );

$client->query('metaWeblog.newMediaObject', 1, $username, $password, $content);
$media = $client->getResponse();
```

Now I also want `alt text` to be posted with the image post. I searched online and found out that `alt-text` is a protected meta and cannot be directly posted using `xml-rpc`.

What modifications can be made to make `alt-text` posting possible via `xml-rpc` **or** is there a way to **by default fill `alt text` with the title** of image using `functions.php`?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to extend the Wordpress server-side XMLRPC code with a plugin based on https://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-wordpress/issues/43

Then call this method via XMLRPC once you have an attachment id.